# How to set ajax response.responseText as global JS variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to be able to add the responseText of my ajax code to variable so that I can add it to a paragraph of text, but I have basicly no experience in any kind of JS ecept for what I have been able to google me to during this project, so any help would be much appriciated.

My code looks like this:

```js
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ml/",
                contentType: "application/base64",
                data: window.dataURL,
                dataType: "base64",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
```

I then need to be able to place the variable in like this:

```
var para = document.getElementById("canvasimgtext");
        para.textContent = responseText
```

The full extend of the function they are part of:

```
function save() {
        window.dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").width = 32;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").height = 32;

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ml/",
                contentType: "application/base64",
                data: window.dataURL,
                dataType: "base64",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });

        var para = document.getElementById("canvasimgtext");
        para.textContent = responseText
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Tried the answers given but with no luck:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ml/",
                contentType: "application/base64",
                data: window.dataURL,
                dataType: "base64",
                success: function(response) {
                    var para = document.getElementById("canvasimgtext");
                    para.textContent = response;
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
```

When placed here the text no longer appears when the button is pressed, even if it is passed a simple string and not the variable.

**SECOND EDIT**
Turns out the issue was with Flask not returning success but error so that is the reason nothing was happening.

Comment: make responseText as global and on success assign it response, but why you need it, just use $('#canvasimgtext').text(response); in success, where you did console

Comment: or move your last 2 lines inside success, and use response instead of responsetext

Comment: this is async call move manipulation inside success of fail

Comment: @AhmedSunny unfortunately neither of these solution work.

Comment: are you getting response . ?

Comment: No. When I tried implementing the answer you gave the paragraph simply did not change at all, the rest of the function worked just fine though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `$.ajax()` it's an asynchronous call you will have to run your logic inside the `success` callback.

```
function save() {
  window.dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  document.getElementById('canvasimg').style.border = '2px solid';
  document.getElementById('canvasimg').src = dataURL;
  document.getElementById('canvasimg').style.display = 'inline';
  document.getElementById('canvasimg').width = 32;
  document.getElementById('canvasimg').height = 32;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ml/',
    contentType: 'application/base64',
    data: window.dataURL,
    dataType: 'base64',
    success: function (response) {
      var para = document.getElementById('canvasimgtext');
      para.textContent = response.responseText;
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    },
  });
}
```

Optionally you can promisify the jQuery ajax function and use async/await, read [How to Promisify an Ajax Call](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-promisify-an-ajax-call/)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to display the image after API call in the Canvas.

```
function save() {
  window.dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
  document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
  document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("canvasimg").width = 32;
  document.getElementById("canvasimg").height = 32;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ml/",
    contentType: "application/base64",
    data: window.dataURL,
    dataType: "base64",
    success: function(response) {
      console.log();
      var para = document.getElementById("canvasimgtext");
      para.textContent = response
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

}
```

Since AJAX is an async call, you should update the content of canvas inside the success block of ajax call.

You might want to explore a little more about Aysnc calls and AJAX, here is link for your reference: [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)